# Are TFS Administration Console users stored in tfs_Configuration Database

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

Background:I have TFS 2015 Update 3 supported by a database cluster with 2 nodes. The databases are AlwaysOn. Or at least they should be.

The precipitating event: In the recent past we created a new database by restoring a backup from a detached collection on another TFS server. It all worked as expected until the cluster switched from node A to node B. Then we noticed that new database was not created with AlwaysOn so it was not present on node B.

The Solution: Simple. switch the cluster back to node A and setup AlwaysOn for the new database. Everything worked as expected EXCEPT....

The Puzzle: While the database was on node B as primary due to the unexpected switch from node A the list of users in the Administration Console Users section of the TFS Administration Console was not correct. Some users were missing. When we switched back to node A the complete list of Administration Console users we correct. Since I know the tfs_Configuration database IS setup with AlwaysOn and since I presume that is where the Administration Console users are stored how can this be. I inspected the database separately on each DB server and both contained the list of all the databases. We are certain updates to the Administration Console users predate adding the new collection databases.

So how is it possible the list of Administration console users was incorrect but the list of databases was correct for node B? Is my presumption incorrect and those users stored somewhere else?

Comment: Have you ever checked this issue before creating the new database to restore the backup? or it's just caused by restoring the backup collection database? You can try to add the missed Administrator Console users again in Node B, back to Node A  then back to Node B again to check if the missed users displayed there this time. Normally the data should be sync if you set the cluster. So, make sure you have correctly set the cluster.